# Tool to generate graph data for class dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, static-analysis

Is there some tool that is able **to analyze Java source files**, construct a graph from it **and provide the graph's data in some standard / understandable format**?

It definitively does not need to have GUI, I'd prefer a command line thing so I can process the output by various tools (for segmentation, visualization,...).

Comment: What sort of things do you mean when you say "analyze Java source files"?

Comment: I mean "this class extends this class, implements these interfaces, uses (references these classes, maybe even from what methods) ..." ideally taking inheritance (and maybe access control?) into consideration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class Dependency Tools for Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149416/class-dependency-tools-for-java)

Comment: Does the tool have to work off the source code, or can working off compiled classes work?

Comment: it should be able to analyze source code as the goal is to modify the source code to to change the dependencies and re-iterate - I don't want to include compilation in the loop only to be able to use class-file analyzer

Comment: have you tried FastClasspathScanner? http://stackoverflow.com/a/43095956/1422630

Comment: My friend worked 2016-2017 on adaptation of classycle to produce dependency graph data - see https://bitbucket.org/dulcibela/classycle . I saw some output for Gephi and yEd and it looked good.

Comment: Example using FastClasspathScanner's latest API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51553442/3950982

Answer (score 10):

I'm not certain about command line tools, but I like using ObjectAid for reverse engineering into class diagrams:

http://www.objectaid.com/

You can easily add any class with it's relationships to an ObjectAid graph.  It saves the file in an XML format with the ucls extension.  Here's a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<class-diagram version="1.1.4" icons="true"
always-add-relationships="true" generalizations="true" realizations="true"
associations="true" dependencies="true" nesting-relationships="true">
<class id="1" language="java"
    name="my.classpath.common.controllers.AuthenticationInterceptor"
    project="MyProject"
    file="/SpecialPath/common/controllers/AuthenticationInterceptor.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="205" width="355" x="2222" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="2" language="java"
    name="my.classpath.common.domain.CompanyAssignmentLocation" project="MyProject"
    file="/SpecialPath/common/domain/CompanyAssignmentLocation.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="-1" width="-1" x="856" y="399" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="3" language="java"
    name="my.classpath.common.domain.LocationsSpreadsheetReader" project="MyProject"
    file="/SpecialPath/common/domain/LocationsSpreadsheetReader.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="115" width="348" x="680" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="4" language="java" name="my.classpath.common.domain.Stock"
    project="MyProject" file="/SpecialPath/common/domain/Stock.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="439" width="210" x="430" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="5" language="java" name="my.classpath.common.util.FilesUtil"
    project="MyProject" file="/SpecialPath/common/util/FilesUtil.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="277" width="218" x="1409" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="6" language="java" name="my.classpath.common.util.MyProjectUtil"
    project="MyProject" file="/SpecialPath/common/util/MyProjectUtil.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="439" width="349" x="41" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="7" language="java" name="my.classpath.common.util.SpringUtil"
    project="MyProject" file="/SpecialPath/common/util/SpringUtil.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="133" width="246" x="1936" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="8" language="java"
name="my.classpath.common.util.MyProjectUserUtil" project="MyProject"
file="/SpecialPath/common/util/MyProjectUserUtil.java" binary="false"
corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="133" width="229" x="1667" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<class id="9" language="java" name="my.classpath.common.util.UnitConversion"
    project="MyProject" file="/SpecialPath/common/util/UnitConversion.java"
    binary="false" corner="BOTTOM_RIGHT">
    <position height="151" width="301" x="1068" y="37" />
    <display autosize="true" stereotype="true" package="true"
        initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true" visibility="true">
        <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
        <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
            private="true" static="true" />
    </display>
</class>
<dependency id="10">
    <end type="SOURCE" refId="3" />
    <end type="TARGET" refId="2" />
</dependency>
<classifier-display autosize="true" stereotype="true"
    package="true" initial-value="false" signature="true" accessors="true"
    visibility="true">
    <attributes public="true" package="true" protected="true"
        private="true" static="true" />
    <operations public="true" package="true" protected="true"
        private="true" static="true" />
</classifier-display>
    <association-display labels="true" multiplicity="true" />
</class-diagram>
```

You can also use PlantUML, but it's better for forward engineering than reverse engineering:

http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/

PlantUML has its own unique syntax that you can get source for, too - but it's not nearly as easy to pull together as ObjectAid

Both of these work as eclipse plug-ins, sorry that I don't know more about any command line tools that might be able to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly I do no want - I need to work with relationships, not presentation. UML diagrams are too coarse grained for my intention.

Comment: Do you have any kind of example output or desired results you can provide?  I'm a little confused by what you want to work with as far as relationships are concerned.

Comment: Anything I could have answered with better to prevent the downvote?

Comment: Ideally the output would be GraphML, but I would be happy with any simple text format, so something like the following would be OK:

class ClassA extends ClassX /
class ClassA uses ClassB /
method fixIt() uses ClassX.how() /
method fixIt() uses ClassX.what /

Comment: ObjectAID generates an XML file - I added a sample of it to my answer.  I don't know that it will do what you're asking, but it looks like maybe it can help you with what you need.

Answer (score 6):

As for a command line tool, you may want to take a look at `jdeps`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jdeps.html

```
jdeps -cp <your cp> -v <path to your .class file>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is [Class Dependency Analyzer (CDA)](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org) .

> The purpose of this tool is to analyze Java™ class files in order to
>   learn more about the dependencies between those classes.

And here is the API:http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/#PluginAPI

Comment: This looks good, probably can be customized to meet some of mi requirements. 

Unfortunately it works on class files, not sources. Also the license is quite restrictive.

Answer (score 4):

From https://github.com/riy/degraph

> You can analyse class files and jars using Degraph and get a graphml file as result. This can be rendered using yed.

Comment: for java all class tree view https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/overview-tree.html

Answer (score 2):

You might [UMLGraph](http://www.umlgraph.org) useful.  It leverages GraphViz/dot as do most such graphing tools.  I haven't used it, so I can't give a review of it, however.

That being said, you might also be able to roll your own minimalistic diagramming tool just using GraphViz and dot.

I've used GraphViz/dot to generate many useful types of diagrams, from visualizations of Spring contexts to IntelliJ module dependencies, to visualizations of complex XML documents.  Look around and see what you find.

Comment: I do not need to generate diagrams, at least not at the moment. And I need to find a tool to collect information from which I would be able to do it first.

Comment: Heh.  You say "graph" I think rendering of the graph :-).  Probably because I'm knee deep in going dot renderings at the moment.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try [Google CodePro Analytix](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/). the tool provides good insight about [dependencies](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/codepro/doc/features/dependencies/dependencies).

However I haven't tried using it from a command-line perspective. I expect it to support reports export, which can be parsed further down the tool-chain.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at it earlier - it was impossible to download it and from the page is heavily GUI oriented, based on Eclipse. I really do not want GUI, I need graph to be able to use generic graph tools on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm use this functionality in my IDE - [IntelliJ Idea](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

See this page for more information and screenshots http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/uml_class_diagram.html

Comment: I know it, definitively too weak for me, although I like IDEA very much.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is still actual, try using the Code Iris plugin. It works with Intellij Idea
http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7324

It provides visual representation of dependency graph on classes, packages and modules level. Moreover, you can export data into json format.

It is still updated and free.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a minimal tool which analyses and displays a graph of dependencies between packages, without much interaction or requiring other programs.

https://github.com/battlesnake/jorgy

It's quite undocumented as it's a quick hack project, but basically you run it and pass the path to your source directory as the first argument to it.

It doesn't care about directory names or file names, but does require:

- `package` declaration in each file.
- Exactly one type defined at the top-level (zero or many inner types nested within that are fine).

You can alter the `GraphStyle` interface in the `Application` class to suit your needs.  This interface provides a way for you to tell the graph builder which dependencies are weak, which should not be shown on the graph, etc.